# Python: How to count the keywords in a py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the number of keywords in another py file
here what's i made:

```
import keyword
infile=open(xx.py,'r')
contentbyword=infile.read().split()
num_of_keywords=0
for word in contentbyword:
        if keyword.iskeyword(word) or keyword.iskeyword(word.replace(':','')):
            num_of_keywords+=1
```

I know it's buggy as even if the keywords is inside a quote or after a # sign, it also counts.

So what is the better way to count the orange-highlighted words (IDLE default) in python? Many Thanks<(_ _)>

Comment: Consider checking word in loop with regex to exclude commented words or these in strings.

Comment: cool
i've tried to look for `".*'.*Keyword.*'.*"` such as `".*'.*as.*'.*"` 
but there's still some exception:
if the line is `print('waste')`, it returns true

any better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this is using the [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module, which takes care of all the edge cases.

```
import token
import keyword
import tokenize

s = open('hi.py').readline
counter = 0
l = []
for i in tokenize.generate_tokens(s):
    if i.type == token.NAME and keyword.iskeyword(i.string):
        counter += 1
        l.append(i.string)

print(counter)
print(l)
```

Comment: Note, this is in Python2. I didn’t notice the python3 tag on your question. the fundamentals of the answer should remain the same though.

Comment: Aaah yes I was trying with the [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module, but I didn't realize that I should be looking at the tokens instead. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

The below code should do for python 2.7 codes.

```
import keyword
import re

handle = open("asdf.py","r")
data = str(handle.read())
data = re.sub(r'".*"', r"",data)
data = re.sub(r'#.*' , r"",data)
mystr = data.split()
mykeys = keyword.kwlist
count=0;
for i in mystr:
    i = re.sub(r':',r'',i)
    if i in mykeys:
        print i
        count=count+1
    else:
        count+=0
print count
```

replace the suitable filename, cheers!

Comment: thanks, but how to deal with `else:` ? It doesn't count

Comment: btw ,`# i am as strong as a bear`, `'i am as strong as a bear'` those 'as' will also be counted and they are not supposed to be counted:(

Comment: Hey! check it now, i've made some changes. It should work!

Comment: thank you very much for the changes and it works. anyway the token method below seems a little bit better. it's really a good lesson from you guys. hope one day i am capable to be the one who help others!

Comment: Definitely you can and you will!

Answer (score 0):

Should consider using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): here a snippet to grep all keywords in a file according a list of keywords:

```
from collections import Counter
def get_kws(file_in, keywords_list):
    with open(file_in) as fin:
        # load all content => not suitable for large file
        content = fin.read()
        # split by non-word 
        words = re.split(r"\W", content)
        counter = Counter(words)
        for word, c in counter.items():
            if word and word in keywords_list:
                yield word, c
```

EDIT:

for the list of python [keywords](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/keywords/) =>

```
keywords_list = ['and', 'del', 'from', 'not', 'while', 'as', 'elif', 'global', 'or', 'with', 'assert', 'else', 'if', 'pass', 'yield', 'break', 'except', 'import', 'print', 'class', 'exec', 'in', 'raise', 'continue', 'finally', 'is', 'return', 'def', 'for', 'lambda', 'try']
```